# Is it possible to see which process is calling the zygote socket?

Tags: linux, processes, selinux, samsung-galaxy-j7

I want to see a verbose from the zygote socket (located in /dev/socket/zygote ) I know i can list all of the services from adb but I wanna see who is calling zygote to fork an specific process. Do you guys know how?

My question does not have an answer, but i made a little code in python that allows me to see the PID of any process listening to the zygote socket

Comment: Sniffing UNIX domain sockets isn't straightforward. You need to use `strace` or something similar on process instead.